# Spread props based on conditional check

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to conditionally spread props.  Below, I get an error on the line `{this.props.isAuthenticated && {...this.props}}` saying unexpected token relating to `this` in `this.props.isAuthenticated1`:

```
class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
  render() {

    const ComponentToRender = this.props.component,
      RouteToRender = (
        <Route
          {this.props.isAuthenticated && {...this.props}}
          render={({Component}) =>
            (this.props.isAuthenticated ? (<ComponentToRender {...this.props} />) :
              (<Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: '/login',
                  state: {from: this.props.location
                  }}}
              />))}
        />)

    return (RouteToRender)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing

```
{this.props.isAuthenticated && {...this.props}}
```

to

```
{...(this.props.isAuthenticated && this.props)}
```

will do it.